# Экранирование в POST запросе

Tags: java, кодировка, кириллица, jersey, jax-rs

У меня есть REST-сервис:

```
@Path(value = "post")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String post(String post) {
    System.out.println(post);
    return post;
}
```

На вход подается массив символов в таком виде - `\u0413\u043e\u0440\u0448`

Проблема в том, что он не преобразуется в корректную строку и в таком же виде и остается (а должно быть слово `Горш`). Есть предположение что они, автоматом падая в `String post`, тут же экранируются. В итоге ни `replace`, никакие указания кодировок не помогают. Как преобразовать все это в корректную строку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) есть удобный метод для этого

```
String s = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(post)
```